# How stop receiving xml in Excel File using Phpexcel libraray

Tags: php, phpexcel

what i need :

- i just need data to be save in xlsx format.

  problem im facing:

  - return xml reponse
    here is the response im getting url: http://postimg.org/image/y29ppo2cd/

  here is my header information:

  ```
     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="simple.xlsx"');
      header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    //// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    //header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
   //// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
     header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
     header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
     header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-reva`enter code here`lidate'); // HTTP/1.1
     header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
     $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007'); 
     $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
  ```

Comment: Ensure that your script is outputting absolutely nothing but the datafile stream from the save() method; no spurious whitespaces or BOM heading, no error messages from the rest of the script, etc

Comment: thanks sr  for help ...